# processing some github participation data with YQL,flot & jquery but the JSON isn't cooperating

Tags: jquery, json, flot, yql

so i was messing around with YQL to see if I could grab some data from github to create some dynamic charts with Flot.

In the YQL console, if you use the following query:

select total from json where url="https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/graphs/commit-activity-data" and itemPath="json.json"

you get back the following JSON structure:

```
{
"query": {
"count": 52,
"created": "2013-03-03T19:56:17Z",
"lang": "en-US",
"results": {
 "json": [
  {
   "total": "55"
  },
  {
   "total": "64"
  },
  {
   "total": "50"
  },
  .....
  {
   "total": "24"
  }
 ]
}
}
}
```

count is 52 and it is a rolling 52 week track of commits against a project. I simply want to create a bar graph with flot of this JSON output but I am having trouble rendering the data.

my javascript is likely a mess as i have fallen down a rabbit hole. I just want to create a simple bar chart with 52 bars that represent the number of commits against the project

```
$(function() {
var data = [];
var myData = [];
var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
$.ajax({
    url: "data/latest-yql.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function() {
        //called when complete
        console.log('complete');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var items = data.query.results.json;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var d1 = i;
            var d2 = items[i].total;
            var myData = [
                [d1, d2]
            ];
        };
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{
            data: myData,
            bars: {
                show: true
            }
        }]);
    },
    error: function() {
        //called when there is an error
        console.log('error');
    },
});
```

});

Is there a reasonable solution that I am simply missing due to lack of sleep and staring at the code for a few hours trying various things?

Comment: @DNS

ok, updating the code with:

    myData.push({
     week: d1,
     commits: d2
    });

when i console.log(myData) is returns 52 [object Object]'s

part of the problem here is that flot seems to fail silently. a blank chart is drawn with no data

Comment: are you using server to pull data from YQL? Can make a direct request for same in `jsonp` from YQL with javascript. Defintely need to not create new `var myData` on each pass as mentioned by @DNS

Comment: I can make the jsonp request to yql, I just saved the data locally to not run afoul of any rate limiting while I was iterating on the code

Answer (score 0):

More info on how this is failing would be helpful, but one thing that jumps out at me is that you're resetting myData at every iteration of your loop, and so it always contains just a single datapoint. You already create myData as an array at the top of your ready function, so all you have to do within the loop is push data into it.